# A profile makes mozilla firefox killed. How to repair?

Tags: firefox, memory-management, firefox-profile

Mozilla firefox fills system memory and gets killed during startup if I use my "default" profile, even when started in safe mode. I'm using Kubuntu Linux.

```
$ firefox -safe-mode
Killed
$
```

Upgrading did not help (from firefox 3.6.13+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 to firefox_3.6.16+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_i386.deb).

I created a new profile and it works, safe mode is not required.

How can I repair the "default" profile? I'd like to have access to the data stored there (bookmarks, history, scrapbook, passwords etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new profile and incrementally copy the old data. For every item, close Firefox, copy file(s), start Firefox, and see if it hangs.

- Bookmarks and history: `places.sqlite`
- Passwords: `signons.sqlite`, `cert8.db`, `key3.db`, `secmod.db` (all four must be copied together)
- Session: `sessionstore.js`
- Cookies: `cookies.sqlite`
- Configuration: `prefs.js`
- Extensions: `extensions.ini`, `extensions.sqlite` and `extensions/` directory
- Local storage (incl. some extension data): `localstore.rdf`
- ...